# How to theoretically determine ESR of a capacitor and DCR of an inductor for a buck converter?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, power-electronics

How can we determine ESR of the capacitor and DCR of inductor theoretically in the design of buck converter, without using an LCR meter?

Comment: Why do it theoretically? What theory could possibly be involved that would be more accurate than measuring it or looking in the data sheet?

Answer (score 2):

The ESR and DCR are mostly dependent on the package size of the component itself and thus determined entirely experimentally.  They are usually on the datasheet and they are one of the deciding factors that goes into choosing the component that goes on the circuit board.

Theoretical design of an SMPS is not the greatest idea since they are so fragile.  Theoretical design just doesn't take everything into account properly such as temperature, altitude, frequency, and so many other things.

Answer (score 2):

Both parameters should be specified in the datasheets for the components, as a maximum and perhaps as a typical. If they're not specified, you should not use the part (particularly the capacitor, if it's an electrolytic type).

Here's a [typical Nichicon](http://www.nichicon.co.jp/english/products/pdf/2013fpcap_catalog_hsha.pdf) polymer type:

[image]

[Here](http://www.murata.com/products/capacitor/design/faq/mlcc/property/25.html) is some data on MLCC capacitors.

Here is a typical Bourns inductor data sheet specification:

[image]

Keep in mind that both the ESR and DCR are temperature-dependent and can get worse at extremes of temperature, so the numbers specified may have to be adjusted for worst-case operating conditions. The capacitor datasheet says it won't exceed 150% of the original value, and the DCR will increase by about 0.4% for every degree C of heating.

Comment: The question was how to determine ESR theoretically. Looking up the manufacturer's value in a table (no matter how accurate) hardly qualifies as a useful response.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I see validity in your point. Useful-- I hope so. The theoretical adjustment of parameters for temperature such as tempco of DCR, close to what was asked. A literal answer (if you assume that the numbers are to be from first principles) would have to point the querent to multiphysics software and materials science references, which would probably be OT, as well as involving information not likely available outside of the part manufacturer.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast What inspired this particular answer was the reference to "Designing a Buck Converter" rather than designing components that might be used in a buck converter.

Comment: For the Output capacitor's ESR --> We can determine based on Worst case output voltage tolerance. Output voltage tolerance will depend up on ESR,ESL and Capacitance of Output Capacitor. ESL component we can neglect. Most of the datasheets will specify the formulas to determine the Ripple voltage generated by ESR and Cout separately. use them and we can determine the ESR of Cout. One way to determine the DCR of the inductor is to assume let's say 1% of total output power is lost in DC Losses in DCR ----> Calculate DCR